# Stripping off all p tags inside a div when the div loads

Tags: jquery, unwrap

What is wrong with this code? *I want so when the div loads all the -p- tags inside div "story_L3" are removed leaving the plain text*. simple enough but my code does'nt work, please advice (see example)

```
<div id="story_L3">
  <p class="one">This is a paragraph inside a p element.</p>
  <p class="two">This is a paragraph inside another p element.</p>
</div>


.one{background-color: yellow;}
.two{background-color: pink;}


$('#story_L3').load(function(){
    $('#story_L3').find('p').contents().unwrap(); 
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('#story_L3').load(function(){
    ($('#story_L3 > p').contents().unwrap(); 
});
```

and:

```
$('#story_L3').load(function(){
      if($('#story_L3').find('p').length !== 0){
          $('p').contents().unwrap();     
        }
     });
```

Comment: Instead of div.load try with document.ready function

Comment: You can use directly ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.load()`, directly use [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) code in document-ready handler

```js
$('#story_L3 p').contents().unwrap();
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="story_L3">
  <p class="one">This is a paragraph inside a p element.</p>
  <p class="two">This is a paragraph inside another p element.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#story_L3 > p").contents().unwrap();
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="story_L3">
        <p class="one">This is a paragraph inside a p element.</p>
        <p class="two">This is a paragraph inside another p element.</p>
    </div>
```